# Get arbitrary level parent element (with class selector) of an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, how can I get an element's arbitrary level parent element with a specific selector? I don't know exactly where it is, I just know that it exists somewhere in the DOM above the current element. Here is a primitive example what I want:

```
<div id="world" >
   <div class="forest" id="some_random_forest">
       <div id="groove">
          <div id="oak_tree">
             <div id="a_branch"></div>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div id="south_america">
      <div class="forest" id="rain_forest">
         <div id="jungle_tree"></div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div id="europe">
      <div id="germany">
         <div class="forest" id="black_forest">
             <div id="pine_tree">
                <div id="a_pine_needle"></div>
                <div id="cute_squirrel"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="application/javascript">
   function getParentForest(subject){
      // return the closest div with the class forest to the subject element.
   }

   // So this would be the return values of the following function calls
    getParentForest("#a_branch");   // returns $("#some_random_forest")
    getParentForest("#jungle_tree");   // returns $("#rain_forest")
    getParentForest("#a_pine_needle");   // returns $("#black_forest")
    getParentForest("#cute_squirrel");   // returns $("#black_forest")
</script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
$('#a_branch').closest('.forest');
```